# Using Syntax highligter with Ajax - html and python brush

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am ajax to call a html file from the home page. For the home page, the syntax highlighter is working properly.

But when I call the second html page from the home page within ajax function the syntax highlighter is not working.

The following is the ajax function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#intro_py").click(function() {
        $.get({
            url: "Introduction.html",
            success: function(data,result) {
                $("#div1").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The syntax highlighter is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/scripts/shBrushPython.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">SyntaxHighlighter.all('code');</script>
```

The LOC which I want to highlight in the second page is as follows:

```
<pre name="code" class="brush: py;">
    print ('Hello')
</pre>
```

We have tried with the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#intro_py").click(function() {
            $.get({
                url: "Introduction.html",
                success: function(data,result) {
                    //alert(result);
                    var brush = new SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Python(), data;
                    brush.init({ toolbar: false });
                    data = brush.getHtml(data);
                    $("#div1").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the entire page's html code is getting highlighted rather than the content.

Could anyone please help with this.

I am new to Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxHighlighter.all('code');` is not needed.

Here is a working example (snippet doesn't run because, it doesn't have a `Introduction.html` file).

The python code (or other language) is supposed to be in `pre` tags.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#intro_py").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "get",
      url: "Introduction.html",
      success: function(data) {
        var brush = new SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Python();
        brush.init({ toolbar: false });
        
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = data;
        var preTags = $(el).find("pre");

        for(var i=0;i<preTags.length;i++) {
          var code = $(preTags[i]).text();
          code = brush.getHtml(code);
          $(preTags[i]).html(code);
        }

        $("#div1").html(el.innerHTML);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/scripts/shBrushPython.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SyntaxHighlighter/3.0.83/styles/shCore.min.css">

<input type="button" id="intro_py" value="highlight" />
<div>Text before</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div>Text after</div>
```

Here is the code I used in `Introduction.html`:

```
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<pre name="code" class="brush: py;">
    import re
    for test_string in ['555-1212', 'ILL-EGAL']:
        if re.match(r'^\d{3}-\d{4}$', test_string):
            print test_string, 'is a valid US local phone number'
        else:
            print test_string, 'rejected'
</pre>
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<pre name="code" class="brush: py;">
    import re
    for test_string in ['555-1212', 'ILL-EGAL']:
        if re.match(r'^\d{3}-\d{4}$', test_string):
            print test_string, 'is a valid US local phone number'
        else:
            print test_string, 'rejected'
</pre>
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<pre name="code" class="brush: py;">
    import re
    for test_string in ['555-1212', 'ILL-EGAL']:
        if re.match(r'^\d{3}-\d{4}$', test_string):
            print test_string, 'is a valid US local phone number'
        else:
            print test_string, 'rejected'
</pre>
```

Comment: Still I its highlighting the entire html source code rather than just the contents. The output looks as follows:

    <h1>Python Introduction</h1> 
        <br> 
          
 <h2>Language Introduction</h2> 
        <hr> 
        <p>Python is a dynamic, interpreted (bytecode-compiled) language.</p>

Comment: Still its highlighting the entire html source code rather than just the contents. The output looks as follows:

    <h1>Python Introduction</h1> 
        <br> 
          <hr> 
        <p>Python is a dynamic, interpreted language.</p>

 >>> a = 6           // python           
   >>> a                         
      6

But I want only the contents which looks like this:
Python Introduction
Python is a dynamic, interpreted language & highlight 'print (hello)' within the <pre> tag.
<pre name="code" class="brush: py;">
    print ('Hello')
</pre>

Comment: If I understand correctly, the thing you want is to highlight a part of the `Introduction.html` which is a `pre` tag ?

Comment: yes part of the introduction.html which is a pre tag. But the entire source code of introduction.html is getting highlighted. How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call an Ajax process, you must recall brushes scripts. This is a solution for WordPress theme (v3.0.9b):

```
var initHighlightAfterAjax = function(){
    var syntaxhighlighterCoreJs = $('script#syntaxhighlighter-core-js');
    if (syntaxhighlighterCoreJs.length <= 0) {
        // Core
        $('<script>',{src:'/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/scripts/shCore.js?ver=3.0.9b',id:'syntaxhighlighter-core-js'}).appendTo($('body'));
        // Init HTML Brush
        $('<script>',{src:'/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/scripts/shBrushXml.js?ver=3.0.9b',id:'syntaxhighlighter-brush-xml-js'}).appendTo($('body'));
        // Init CSS Brush
        $('<script>',{src:'/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/scripts/shBrushCss.js?ver=3.0.9b',id:'syntaxhighlighter-brush-css'}).appendTo($('body'));
         // Init JS Brush
         $('<script>',{src:'/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/scripts/shBrushJScript.js?ver=3.0.9b',id:'syntaxhighlighter-brush-js'}).appendTo($('body'));
        // Init PHP Brush
        $('<script>',{src:'/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/scripts/shBrushPhp.js?ver=3.0.9b',id:'syntaxhighlighter-brush-php'}).appendTo($('body'));
        // Init selected theme
        $('<style>',{id:'SyntaxHighlighter',html:'@import url("/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/styles/shCore.css?ver=3.0.9b"); @import url("/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/styles/shThemeRDark.css?ver=3.0.9b"); '}).appendTo($('head'));
    }
    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
 }
```

Insert your Ajax success process:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
    initHighlightAfterAjax(); // init after success
 }
})
```